# Setting headers for CakePHP Controller unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm writing some unit tests for a Controller in which the response behavior differs slightly, depending on whether `$this->request->is('ajax')`.  I've been looking over the [documentation for testing controllers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-controllers), but I can't seem to find a way to simulate a request made via AJAX.

Is there a way to send headers to `testAction()` so I can set the X-Requested-With header?

**Edit:** You can work around this by editing the superglobals.  Anyone have a less hacky solution?

Comment: If you're just trying to break into a certain code block you could just check if the request ISNT ajax otherwise why can't you send an ajax request?

Comment: I'm not sure what your suggesting @NickSavage.  Having to edit the code defeats the purpose of a unit test, and you can't reliably make an http request against your own code within a unit test, hence the need to mock up the inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to manually declare the necessary environment variable for the duration of your test:

```
$_ENV['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
// Run your AJAX test...
unset($_ENV['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']);
```