# Simulating ajax request in CakePHP unit test

Tags: php, ajax, unit-testing, cakephp

I have tried various methods, including setting the headers as suggested by this post [Setting headers for CakePHP Controller unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405936/setting-headers-for-cakephp-controller-unit-tests) but I can't seem to simultae an ajax request in my controller unit test.

I have this condition

```
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
```

and this

```
    if ($this->params['isAjax'] == 1) {
```

but the conditions are not satisfied., I even tried setting the array value `$this->params['isAjax'] = 1;` but I got an error

```
Indirect modification of overloaded property RoomController::$params has no effect
```

My question is how can I successfully simulate an ajax request when unit testing a controller in cakePHP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to stick to $this->request ($this->request->params in your case).
As $this->params itself is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

But in your case, all you need to do is to set the right $_SERVER or $_ENV key in your test case:

```
testSomeAjaxAction() {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $url = Router::url(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'update', 'ext' => 'json', '?' => array('value' => 2)));
    $options = array(
        'return' => 'vars'
    );
    $result = $this->testAction($url, $options);
    // Assert
}
```

Then `if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {}` in your code will work just fine.

See https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/wiki/Testing#testing-controllers

Comment: I ended up with having to "unset" the global variable after the test - otherwise it was effecting following tests. So I put $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = '' as last line of the ajax test.

Answer (score 0):

Cake (now? as of v3.x, anyway) has a method in its `IntegrationTestTrait` called  `configRequest()` that will handle this.  In this case, add

```
$this->configRequest([
    'headers' => ['X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']
]);
```

before sending the request, and it will trigger the `$this->request->is('ajax')` conditional.

In addition, as regards the response above, you won't need to unset this after the test, as it gets reset in the `parent::tearDown()`.

[Documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html#setting-up-the-request)